# how to read php content in a html file using file_get_contents

Tags: php

I want to get the html structure of test.php (which has included file) to index.php. This is what I've done so far...

/* index.php */

```
<?php
$url = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

$html = file_get_contents($url);
$d = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$d->formatOutput = true;
$d->loadHTML($html);
$x = new DOMXPath($d);

foreach ($x->query('//*[text()[contains(., "!TEXT")]]') as $node) {
    if(!empty($node->nodeValue)){

            /////

    }
}

echo $d->saveHTML();
?>
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* test.php */

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>sample</p>
<?php include('inc.php'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

////////////////////////////////////////

I'm keep getting this result (in DOM Inspector)

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>sample</p>
<!--?php include('inc.php'); ?-->



</body></html>
```

Comment: Looks like your webserver doesn't interpret php properly: create a file named test.php with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` inside, it should return a lot of infos. If not, this means your php installation is wrong

Comment: @Manu I've got PHP Version 5.5.12 with list of infos...

Comment: @ceejayoz please don't mark this as a duplicate because the issue is still remaining.

Comment: @Dev `file_get_contents` on a local PHP file will not *execute* the PHP in that file. The duplicate thread offers a way to get that to work. Read it and implement, or explain why it doesn't fix your issue.